# double print before allowed to respond

Tags: java

I'm still new to programming and have been trying to learn how to fix this code
im trying to input and record a username and password depending on how many users I input, but when i run it it prints out the ***"whats your username?"*** question twice before i'm allowed to give a response. I've narrowed the problem down to the **user[i]=in.nextLine() part**

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("How many Users?");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = in.nextInt();
    String[] user;
    user = new String[x];
    String[] pass;
    pass = new String[x];

    for(int i=0; i<x;i++){
        System.out.println("What is your Username?");
        user[i] = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: Does it let you input x usernames or can you only input x-1 users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `in.nextLine();` after `int x = in.nextInt();` to consume and ignore the new line character left over by call to `nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

When you use a scanner **it consume only the bytes needed for the requested token**.

If the first call is to get the number of users (`nextInt`) it reads only the minimum number of digits composing it **and leave the `\n`** (new line character) **not consuming it**.

Because you are asking for the next line on the loop the first nextLine use only the \n.

So the best solution to make your code correct is to add a

```
in.nextLine();
```

before the `for` loop.